# JSONP in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jsonp

I have a problem with using the jQuery JSONP method `$.getJSON` in CodeIgniter. The URL from which the JSON is grabbed from is the following:

```
http://spinly.000space.com/index.php/admin/isloggedin
```

The Problem is that I have a `demo.html` file that runs the `$.getJSON` method, and grabs the data from the URL I denoted above.

**demo.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://www.spinly.000space.com/public/js/jquery.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var myurl = "http://spinly.000space.com/index.php/admin/isloggedin/&jsoncallback=?";

    //myurl = "http://com.lnk.bz/jsonp.php?sleep=3&jsoncallback=?";
    $.getJSON(myurl,function(adat) {
        alert(adat);
     //   clearTimeout(t);
    }); 

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="images">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run `demo.html` nothing happens. As you can see, it's supposed to alert the data returned when I change the URL to a another one that doesn't use CodeIgniter as the framework. I get alert function running, but in this case, while using the URL that's backed up with CodeIgniter, it doesn't work. Does anyone have a solution to my problem? I'd really appreciate if you gave me some feedback. Thanks in advance!

Comment: looking for a good way to implement jsonp in CI ...

Comment: Before elaborate more, can you specify what version CI you use, and is it "Core" or "Reactor" ?

Comment: This URL doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The ampersand in your url is wrong:

```
loggedin/&jsoncallback=?
```

It should be something along the lines of

```
loggedin/?jsoncallback=?
```

Running that i get the response of

```
jsonp123( ...
```

Which means it attempts to call the jsonp123 function, and the adat part of your code is never used at this point.

Comment: postpostmodern: I've changed the code, and now http://spinly.000space.com/index.php/admin/isloggedin/ displays {"title":"user online","user":{"online":"yes"}} and still it doesn't work.

Comment: The getJson method makes a new function which is replaced into your url, and as sent is something like: 

loggedin/?jsoncallback=jsonp1239837994134&_=1239838173986

Try replacing your php with this:

$cb = $_GET['jsoncallback'];
echo $cb;
echo '({"test":true})';

It is a little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

By default CI doesn't allow query strings, so did you enable **enable_query_strings** in your config.php?

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

i think the issue that you are facing is because of the restriction by browsers on not allowing cross domain requests. I am guessing that you are hosting your app on some other domain/sub-domain and that is what is causing this issue.

What you need to use is JSONP i.e Json with padding. Details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Look at jsonp in jquerys ajax api here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you have `$config['allow_get_array']` set to `TRUE` in config.php. This will allow you to use

`$this->input->get();`

in your controllers.